# Magento catalog/seo_sitemap/product/ empty

Tags: layout, cms, contact-us

We are using Magento 1.9.0.1 and see that `Magento catalog/seo_sitemap/product/ empty` is completely empty. Whilst `catalog/seo_sitemap/category/` is working fine.

Is there a known problem with seo_sitemap/product? [we sell configurable products with underlying simple products with sizes: so ideally I would expect a list of all configurable products that are active, visible and in stock]